# Problemas con la librería numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Buenas tardes o noches a todos, el problema que tengo es que estoy trabajando con la librería numpy, la instale y la operación fue exitosa fig (1), pero al momento de compilar me aparece un error que dice ningún modulo llamado numpy ¨ fig(2). Mi versión de Python es la 3.8 ¿Qué me sugieren para solucionar este problema?
Muchas gracias.

[image: Fig(1)]

[image: Fig(2)]

Comment: aparentemente estas usando un **virtual enviroment**, tambien tienes que instalarlo ahi

Comment: Instala a través de la GUI de PyCharm, así te aseguras de instalar en el entorno que estás usando: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html